# Media not showing up for preview

Tags: kentico

I've had a report from a user whereby the preview link functionality isn't working quite right. The process is simple, go to properties, click on show preview and that should then generate a link that can be forwarded.

However the preview that's being shown doesn't show media that has been linked in as a background image. The URL that has been generated for the image doesn't resolve correctly (Access Denied "This virtual context URL is not valid.").

Oddly this isn't consistent, some components show the background correctly, some do not but there's no real cause I can put my finger on, for example, one web part works fine on one page but the same web part doesn't on another page with the exact same template, etc. just some minor copy changes.

Comment: What are the differences in the image/background links? Links on the preview page leading to other parts of the website are intentionally disabled with the exception of links leading to other domains. (https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-website-content/working-with-pages/sending-links-to-unpublished-pages)

Comment: The only difference I can see is one I expected which is to prepend it with a path that's meant to be displaying the asset as *I* view it e.g.:

background-image: url(/cmsctx/pv/[myusername]/culture/en-GB/wg/c5801414-2747-49f0-833c-49dc34b9cfba/h/0770dfbf26785155d8772df435ae1fac9f7c7f901641ecd8518da234fc8242db/-/getmedia/ed14e97f-69ab-4909-9348-90bcc3225b95/nuclear-medicine-ctaimagerow-m-613327714.jpg?width=600&height=800&ext=.jpg);

It's particularly mystifying me now as some images work, some don't and they have the same permissions.

Comment: So, we are talking about resources like CSS background images and so on? Not page attachments or media files? What are the links to the resources in your CSS? You should be using relative paths like described in this discussion: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/cannot-view-images-or-load-scripts-from-mvc-application-in-page-builder-preview In the URL you provided - it is from the admin UI where it is generated with some user context and security hash - and this won't work on the live site.

Comment: I mean we are talking background-image properties pulled from the media library but surely the whole point of the shareable preview link was to provide exactly the functionality you're suggesting? It should work by providing a URL that can give anyone the same preview as the current user who's requested it hence why it has the cmsctx preappended to it?